# Pass specific address in Web3J send method

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3j, ethereumj, java

How to pass specific  address in send method in **Web3J**?

For example, using web3 javascript library, we can pass from address like below.

```
contract.someMethod().send({ from: this.props.accounts[0] })
```

But in the Java wrapper, there are no parameters defined for `send()` method.

Is there a way to pass specific address in **web3j**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an `unsigned` transaction and let the client pick up the account `from` to use to sign the transaction. You can do the following:

**Ether transaction**

```
Transaction transaction = Transaction.createEtherTransaction(from, nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, value);
web3.ethSendTransaction(transaction);
```

**Smart contract transaction**

```
Function function = new Function<>(
        "functionName",  // function we're calling
        Arrays.asList(new Type(value), ...),  // Parameters to pass as Solidity Types
        Arrays.asList(new TypeReference<Type>() {}, ...));

String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function)
Transaction transaction = Transaction.createContractTransaction(from, nonce, gasPrice, encodedFunction);
web3.ethSendTransaction(transaction);
```

---

**Transaction Receipt:**

```
String txHash = web3.ethSendTransaction(transaction).send().getTransactionHash();

EthGetTransactionReceipt transactionReceipt =
         web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(txHash).send();

if (transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt.isPresent()) {
    String contractAddress = transactionReceipt.get().getContractAddress();
} else {
    // try again until it's mined
}
```

Comment: Thanks, then where to pass this Transaction instance to get transaction receipt?

Comment: Just edited my answer, that should give you a hint

Comment: How to generate nonce?

Comment: There is one last simple question: How to pass nonce? I didn't find the documentation for it.

Comment: Ok. I found  this:      EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = serverWeb3j.ethGetTransactionCount(from, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
        BigInteger nonce = ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();

Comment: Can you please answer one more question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65142/how-does-ethereum-smart-contract-work-on-mobile-client I would appreciate any advice you give.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this ?

```
contract.someMethod(parameter, {from: address, gas: 3000000},
function(err, res){

    if(!err){
        console.log("address sent ");    
    }
});
```

Comment: I am asking about web3j which is a java wrapper over web3 javascript library.